# if itemcontainerstyle is inside DataTemplate and a call the the main window is used an System.NullReferenceExc on start-up but works fine if ignored

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, null, initialization

when i try to call a event from the main wind if a control is in a template in itemcontainerstyle
when the run a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' is displayed over InitializeComponent(); which if i continue it works fine as indented which is weird because an error message is normally there to tell you if something didn't work

below is the a cut down vision of my program only the things that case the error message to come up (i have tried it in different templates)

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace wpf_test_zone
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

```html
       Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabcontrol_1">
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <Grid>
                        <TabControl x:Name="tabcontrol_2">
                            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                
                                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Button x:Name="but" Click="test">
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </TabControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
        
    </Grid>
```

edit -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[the error message that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGiC9.png)

Comment: In the *Debug >> Exceptions* window put a check mark to break when the `System.NullReferenceException` type is thrown.  Then go to *Debug >> Options* and under the "General" category, un-check the box that says "Enable Just My Code" and check the box that says "Enable .NET Framework Source Stepping"  Then Debug a debug build and look at where the debugger breaks when that exception occurs.  You'll likely be able to answer your own question that way

Comment: the error originates where i expect it to on the line where it binds the method but if i continue its fine with carrying on

Comment: If you set up things as I mentioned above, when the exception occurs, the Visual Studio debugger should take you right to the exact, offending line -- presumably inside .NET or .WPF code -- where the exception occurs.  You should be able to see what is NULL.    Not just in your code but in the code your code calls.   Inside an assembly that does not belong to your codebase.    Regardless, it seems that whatever the reason, WPF is expecting this exception and properly catching it for you.  There are a couple of places in there that it happens.